# How can I manipulate file names using bash and sed?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to loop through all the files in a directory.

I want to do some stuff on each file (convert it to xml, not included in example), then write the file to a new directory structure.

```
for file in `find /home/devel/stuff/static/ -iname "*.pdf"`;
do
  echo $file;
  sed -e 's/static/changethis/' $file > newfile +".xml";
  echo $newfile;
done
```

I want the results to be:

$file => `/home/devel/stuff/static/2002/hello.txt`

$newfile => `/home/devel/stuff/changethis/2002/hello.txt.xml`

How do I have to change my `sed` line?

Answer (score 13):

If you need to rename multiple files, I would suggest to use `rename` command:

```
# remove "-n" after you verify it is what you need
rename -n 's/hello/hi/g' $(find /home/devel/stuff/static/ -type f)
```

or, if you don't have `rename` try this:

```
find /home/devel/stuff/static/ -type f | while read FILE
do
    # modify line below to do what you need, then remove leading "echo" 
    echo mv $FILE $(echo $FILE | sed 's/hello/hi/g')
done
```

Comment: Which rename is this? I assume the perl one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename

Comment: Very nice protection against reckless copy-pasting :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to change the filename? Then

```
for file in /home/devel/stuff/static/*/*.txt
do
    echo "Moving $file"
    mv "$file" "${file/static/changethis}.xml"
done
```

Please make sure `/home/devel/stuff/static/*/*.txt` is what you want before using the script.

Comment: no. I am trying to get the filename, append ".xml" and put it in a diff directory

Comment: @Mu Qiao: Your wildcard expansion will miss any .txt file in the static directory. The find command will not.

Comment: @Hai Vu, yes that's right. But I don't actually know if the op has any txt files in the static directory. That's partly why I let him to confirm if the path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to create the name of the new file based on the name of the initial file. The obvious solution is:

```
newfile=${file/static/changethis}.xml
```

Second you have to make sure that the new directory exists or create it if not:

```
mkdir -p $(dirname $newfile)
```

Then you can do something with your file:

```
doSomething < $file > $newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do the `for` loop because of the possibility of overloading your command line. Command lines have a limited length, and if you overload it, it'll simply drop off the excess without giving you any warning. It might work if your find returns 100 file. It might work if it returns 1000 files, but it might fail if your find returns 1000 files and you'll never know.

The best way to handle this is to pipe the find into a while read statement as [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman).

The sed command only works on STDIN and on files, but not on file names, so if you want to munge your file name, you'll have to do something like this:

```
$newname="$(echo $oldname | sed 's/old/new/')"
```

to get the new name of the file. The `$()` construct executes the command and puts the results of the command on STDOUT.

So, your script will look something like this:

```
find /home/devel/stuff/static/ -name "*.pdf" | while read $file
do
    echo $file;
    newfile="$(echo $file | sed -e 's/static/changethis/')"
    newfile="$newfile.xml"
    echo $newfile;
 done
```

Now, since you're renaming the file directory, you'll have to make sure the directory exists before you do your move or copy:

```
find /home/devel/stuff/static/ -name "*.pdf" | while read $file
do
    echo $file;
    newfile="$(echo $file | sed -e 's/static/changethis/')"
    newfile="$newfile.xml"
    echo $newfile;

    #Check for directory and create it if it doesn't exist
    $dirname=$(dirname "$newfile")
    if [ ! -d "$dirname" ]
    then
        mkdir -p "$dirname"
    fi

    #Directory now exists, so you can do the move
    mv "$file" "$newfile"
 done
```

Note the quotation marks to handle the case there's a space in the file name.

By the way, instead of doing this:

```
if [ ! -d "$dirname" ]
then
    mkdir -p "$dirname"
fi
```

You can do this:

```
[ -d "$dirname"] || mkdir -p "$dirname"
```

The `||`  means to execute the following command only if the test isn't true. Thus, if [ -d "$dirname" ] is a false statement (the directory doesn't exist), you run `mkdir`.

It's a fairly common shortcut when you see shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ... | while read file; do
  newfile=$(basename "$file").xml;
  do something to "$file" > "$somedir/$newfile"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OUTPUT="$(pwd)";
for file in `find . -iname "*.pdf"`;
do
  echo $file;
  cp $file $file.xml
  echo "file created in directory = {$OUTPUT}"
done
```

This will create a new file with name whatyourfilename.xml, for hello.pdf the new file created would be hello.pdf.xml, basically it creates a new file with .xml appended at the end.

Remember the above script finds files in the directory `/home/devel/stuff/static/` whose file names match the matcher string of the find command (in this case *.pdf), and copies it to your present working directory.

The find command in this particular script only finds files with filenames ending with .pdf If you wanted to run this script for files with file names ending with .txt, then you need to change the find command to this `find /home/devel/stuff/static/ -iname "*.txt"`,

Answer (score 0):

Once I wanted to remove trailing `-min` from my files. i.e. wanted `alg-min.jpg` to turn into `alg.jpg`. so after some struggle, managed to figure something like this:

```
for f in *; do echo $f; mv $f $(echo $f | sed 's/-min//g');done;
```

Hope this helps someone willing to **REMOVE** or **SUBTITUDE** some part of their file names.