# Get the Perl rename utility instead of the built-in rename

Tags: linux, perl, bash, rename, file-rename

Many sites (including various SO articles) talk about using "rename" using Perl expressions to rename files.

This would be perfect, but apparently this is not the rename utility I have, and none of these articles seem to comprehend that there are multiple versions of "rename" and I can't seem to find where to get version that accepts Perl expressions.

How can I get my hands on the more powerful rename utility mentioned [here](http://linuxaria.com/howto/mass-renaming-files-on-linux?lang=en), [here](http://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6329558/1542702)?

I'm running Fedora 20. My current rename command is from the `util-linux` package and apparently I need the Perl version, which is better.

Comment: If you have perl, it should be available as `prename` too.

Comment: @devnull I have perl, but `man prename`, `prename`, and `sudo yum search prename` all come back empty handed.

Comment: The script itself can be found at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=303814

Comment: I've downloaded the script, fixed inserted linebreaks, and used it; it works correctly. I'd be willing to mark 'answered' if someone could put a clean download (is there one with a man page?) and how to use it globally instead of writing my own alias to hit a perl file I've stuck somewhere.

Comment: In case you don't have root access in your machine, here is a gist with the script (necessary linebreaks fixed, as mentioned by @WorldsEndless): https://gist.github.com/rocarvaj/6abf7dd1e083963a596430ac43f88e34

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can only speak for Debian. The two programs are called

- `/usr/bin/rename.ul` from the `util-linux` package (hence the .ul suffix)
- `/usr/bin/prename` from the `perl` package

The actual `rename` command works via the `/etc/alternatives` mechanism, whereby

- `/usr/bin/rename` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/rename`
- `/etc/alternatives/rename` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/prename`

The same problem has been bugging me on Cygwin, which is a Red Hat product, so should be more similar to Fedora. I'll have a look on my company laptop on Monday. And I remember the Perl-rename having worked there sometimes. Probably before I installed `util-linux`.

If you install the Perl-rename to `/usr/local/bin` it will have precedence over `rename` from `util-linux`. Same goes for the manpage when installed to `/usr/local/share/man/man1/`.

I've just created a separate Perl-rename package on Github: https://github.com/subogero/rename

Comment: Looks great. If you'll just add a line I think the answer will be complete: how to install your git package (just a line about "sudo make"). Thanks!

Comment: Re: Cygwin, Red Hat own the copyright on the core `cygwin1.dll` but pays only one full-time developer to work on Cygwin, and she (Corinna Vinschen) doesn't work on Cygwin Perl. The vast majority of Cygwin work is done by community volunteers, and they are not constrained in making decisions to match Fedora. Cygwin Perl [is currently maintained](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-pkg-maint) by several people, none of whom get paid by Red Hat to work on Cygwin. (Eric Blake, a Red Hat employee, maintains the `perl-error` package, but he's publicly stated that his Cygwin work is off the clock.)

Comment: That's amazing. And Cygwin's been the most reliable piece of software on Windows for ages. :-)

Comment: If you wanted to contribute a `perl-rename` package, I'd support it. You'll notice my name on the Cygwin package maintainer list, too. And no, I don't want to create that package. My personal choice for fancy renaming – when Bash one-liners aren't appropriate — is `mmv` and I hardly ever need to use it.

Answer (score 19):

You can install it using [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/), which is the perl repository similar to pip for python.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-install-perl-modules-manually-and-using-cpan-command/) on using cpan.

If you try to run rename it it looks like this

> rename --help
>    call: rename from to files...

To install the perl rename you can do the following. You might need to install a few dependencies, you can generally just push enter

> cpan
>   cpan[1](http://search.cpan.org/)> install File::Rename
>   CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
>   Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
>    Database was generated on Wed, 30 Sep 2015 08:17:02 GMT
>    Running install for module 'File::Rename'
>   ....
>   Running Build install
>   Installing /usr/local/share/man/man1/rename.1
>   Installing /usr/local/share/perl5/File/Rename.pm
>   Installing /usr/local/share/man/man3/File::Rename.3pm
>   Installing /usr/local/bin/rename
>   Writing /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/File/Rename/.packlist
>    RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20.tar.gz
>    ./Build install  -- OK

That is how you would install the rename from cpan.
Next is to get it working on your system. As you might have more then one rename installed.

```
which rename  
/usr/bin/rename
```

When you actually want this one.

```
/usr/local/bin/rename --help
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E *perlexpr*]*|*perlexpr*
    [ *files* ]

Options:
    -v, -verbose
            Verbose: print names of files successfully renamed.

    -n, -nono
            No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename.

    -f, -force
            Over write: allow existing files to be over-written.

    -h, -help
            Help: print SYNOPSIS and OPTIONS.

    -m, -man
            Manual: print manual page.

    -V, -version
            Version: show version number.

    -e      Expression: code to act on files name.

            May be repeated to build up code (like "perl -e"). If no -e, the
            first argument is used as code.

    -E      Statement: code to act on files name, as -e but terminated by
            ';'.
```

I just put it into `/usr/bin/` but with a slight different name to make sure I did not break any existing scripts / programs the depend on the old one.

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/rename /usr/bin/rename.pl
```

Comment: For my case, i need `sudo cpan`.

Comment: Even `sudo cpan` and the install didn't give me this script.  Fedora 24.  Is it because I already installed the GitHub answer?  I had uninstalled that, and also directly referenced `/usr/bin/rename`, but didn't get this 'super-powered' version.

Comment: @Pysis It didn't install `rename` for me, either.  It did install a `file-rename` that seems to be the same program.  EDIT: I'm using Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Ran this on openSuse and it replaced the existing /usr/bin/rename which is not what I wanted, I wanted to have both. Any idea how to get the old one back?

Answer (score 5):

On RedHat 8.4 (but may work on Fedora)

```
sudo yum install perl-CPAN
sudo cpan
install module::Build
install File::Rename
```

than you can create an alias:

```
alias prename='/usr/local/bin/rename'
```

An example:

```
touch pic.jpeg
prename 's/\.jpeg$/.jpg/' *.jpeg
```

Here you create an empty file with the .jpeg extension. The next line renames all the files with .jpeg extension in the current directory: it removes the e from the jpeg extension of these files. (The first line is there to be sure that there is at least one file like that in the directory.)

(On Debian/Ubuntu you can install the `rename` package, then you'll have the `rename` command same as the `prename` above. Also read SzG's answer about alternatives and symbolic links: it may or may not be as simple as I wrote.

Alternatively you [need to install the libpath-tiny-perl package to install CPAN](https://linuxhint.com/install_perl_modules_debian_linux/).)

Answer (score 4):

I had to do the following:

```
# In bash
sudo yum install perl-CPAN
sudo cpan

# In CPAN shell
install Module::Build
install File::Rename
```

Answer (score 2):

For Arch Linux, its

```
sudo pacman -S perl-rename
```

Answer (score 1):

For Debian-family (`.deb`) distros, I recommend @SzG's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22578623/4279440).

For RedHat-family (`.rpm`) distros (e.g. Fedora), if your time is *precious* (like mine), you can download, compile, and install, from source via [`cpan`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/rename/) in one, **terse** command:

```
# Install (replace `rename-1.9` below with another version if desired)
curl -L "http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PE/PEDERST/rename-1.9.tar.gz" | tar -xz && ( cd "rename-1.9"; perl "Makefile.PL"; make && make install )

# Cleanup
rm -rf "rename-1.9"
```

**Note:**

> `INSTALL_BASE` can be set to modify the base installation directory.
>
> **e.g.** `perl "Makefile.PL" INSTALL_BASE=/usr/local`
>
> [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/543918/4279440)

Comment: For RedHat-family distros you should be able to just `yum install prename`.  The 'prename' package is in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

Answer (score 1):

I created a post about Perl's rename for many distro:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574

- `rpm` based distros:

  - `dnf install prename`
- `archlinux`:

  - `pacman -S perl-rename`
- `*BSD`:

  - `pkg install p5-File-Rename`
- `Debian like/Ubuntu`

  - `apt install rename`
- `slackware`:

  - [slackbuild](https://slackbuilds.org/repository/15.0/system/rename.pl/)

Answer (score -1):

I recently had to install the glorious Perl `rename` package to Alpine Linux in a Docker container for a Gitlab CI/CD operation:

```
apk update
apk add --no-cache make perl-utils
cpan File::Rename
```