# rename -n option seems not available under cygwin

Tags: regex, unix, cygwin, rename

I'm trying to **rename** several files at once with **cygwin** and would like to use the rename command.
I would like to use the -n option ... no action. It feels saver to me because I'm no regex guru.

I found helful sources and they tell me that there should be this option:

```
-n, --no-act    No Action: show what files would have been renamed.
```

I am using **cygwin** and when I show the rename manual the -n option seems not available:

```
RENAME(1)                                                                           User Commands                                                                           RENAME(1)

NAME
       rename - rename files

SYNOPSIS
       rename [options] expression replacement file...

DESCRIPTION
       rename will rename the specified files by replacing the first occurrence of expression in their name by replacement.

OPTIONS
       -v, --verbose
              Give visual feedback which files where renamed, if any.

       -V, --version
              Display version information and exit.

       -s, --symlink
              Peform rename on symlink target

       -h, --help
              Display help text and exit.
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Cygwin` `rename` program comes from `util-linux`, see the bottom of `man rename`:

> The rename command is part of the util-linux package and is available
>   from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/.

On some (most?) Linux distributions `rename` is a short `Perl` script. If you have `Perl` installed on your `Cygwin` installation just copy `rename` script and run it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have installed perl on Cygwin. How do I find the perl rename script?

Comment: no problem, if it works for you please mark it as accepted so that other SE users know it's solved

Comment: You can get it here: https://github.com/subogero/rename/blob/master/rename. From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename)

Comment: @elToro You must have edited your comment after I had seen it for the first time. Use `type rename` to learn where `rename` lives on your Linux system or download it from the Internet as explained in the above comment.