# Renaming multiple files in Linux/Unix

Tags: bash, unix, rename

I have over a thousand files of similar names in a directory and wish to do a rename. The files are of this format

```
GW_LGMS01-50160306185154-01375272.CDR
GW_LGMS01-50160306237154-01375272.CDR.00001    
GW_LGMS02-50160306133554-02308872.CDR
GW_LGMS02-50160306137554-02308872.CDR.00014
GW_LGMS03-50160306221836-02217475.CDR.00001
GW_LGMS03-50160306235132-02217475.CDR
```

I want to do a rename on all of them at once to append a `0-` before `50160306` on all of them. That is,

```
GW_LGMS01-0-50160306185154-01375272.CDR
GW_LGMS01-0-50160306237154-01375272.CDR.00001    
GW_LGMS02-0-50160306133554-02308872.CDR
GW_LGMS02-0-50160306137554-02308872.CDR.00014
GW_LGMS03-0-50160306221836-02217475.CDR.00001
GW_LGMS03-0-50160306235132-02217475.CDR
```

`50160306` is what all the files have in common.

Comment: What shell are you working in? Bash?

Comment: Use `prename` http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/prename/ or `rename` http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Comment: Bash. Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `-50160306` is unique in the file names, and that you are using a shell that understands `${parameter/pattern/string}` (Bash, KornShell, etc.):

```
for f in *.CDR*; do
  echo mv "$f" "${f/-50160306/-0-50160306}"
done
```

Do this with the `echo` in place to see what would happen, then remove the `echo` when you are sure it does the right thing.

If you are afraid to mess up, just put the files with the new names in a new folder:

```
mkdir renamed

for f in *.CDR*; do
  cp "$f" renamed/"${f/-50160306/-0-50160306}"
done
```

Comment: I'm speechless. Words are not enough. Thanks so much. it did the exact thing I wanted. But If my understanding is correct, the `echo` displays the outcome of the rename?

Comment: I was indeed afraid but I had to just summon the courage. You might have guessed right, I'm a "newbie". I also noticed that the rename over-wrote the old name. hope the contents won't be affected?

Comment: @oak Removing the `echo` from the first example loop will move the file to its new name (i.e. "rename the file"). Otherwise it will just show what command would have been executed.

Comment: I asked because when I used `echo`, it displays a line my line rename of the real file but it didn't replace them so I edited the script and removed `echo` like you suggested. It did the rename and replaced the old filename with the new file name. Much appreciated.

Comment: I want to ask another question(new thread) based on the reply you gave me. Your reply will be much appreciated.

Comment: @oak Do ask. I will be away for a bit, but will get to it when I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in * ; do
    mv "$i" "$(printf '%s' "$i" | sed 's/\(50160306.*\)/0-\1/')"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two `rename` tools floating around: one is part of the util-linux package, the other is Perl based (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22578623/3266847) for details). To find out which one you have, check at the end of the man page (`man rename`).

With the util-linux version, you can rename your files as follows:

```
rename 50160306 0-50160306 *
```

and for the Perl based version, it would be (untested!)

```
rename 's/50160306/0-$&/' *
```

Be aware that there are no safeguards with these commands – test them on a small sample before you use them.