# How to get sed or awk commands in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to change the filename from 
`prod.test.PVSREGPLUS20170915-6777.DAT.gpg`
to 
`PVSREGPLUS20170915-0003.DAT.gpg`

I used this

```
DTE=$(date +%I);ls  prod.test* |cut -f 3,4,5 -d .|sed "s/\-/-00$DTE/" |cut -c 1-23,28-35
```

My problem is I need this command in a shell script

```
"#! /bin/bash

DTE=$(date +%I)

newfile=$(ls  prod.test* |cut -f 3,4,5 -d .|sed "s/-*./$DTE/"|cut -c 1-23,28-35
```

The sed can't do expansion, would awk be able to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `The sed can't do expansion`? sed can do the expansion just fine. Your shell script has other issues of course (e.g. extra `"` at the start and missing `)` at the end). Run it through `shellcheck`.

Comment: You changed the `sed` command: the version in your script will change the **first character** to the DTE value.

Comment: Tangential to the question, I'd suggest looking into `perl-rename` (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename)).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with a for-loop over a glob pattern, then use paramater expansion to remove the prefix

```
prefix="prod.test."
hour=$(date '+%I')
for f in "$prefix"*; do 
    new=$( echo "${f#$prefix}" | sed 's/-[[:digit:]]\+/-00'"$hour"'/' )
    echo mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

We really don't need sed: extended patterns and more parameter expansion

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in "$prefix"*; do 
    new=${f#$prefix}
    new=${new/-+([0-9])/-00$hour}
    echo mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

Remove "echo" if it looks good.

Or, with the perl `rename` as suggested in the comments:

```
rename -v -n 's/prod\.test\.//; use Time::Piece; s{-\d+}{"-00" . (localtime)->strftime("%I") }e' prod.test.*
```

Remove "-n" if it looks good.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it, time to hit the books harder. What do you guys recommend. Glenn, you're a master!