# bash change absolute path in file line by line for script creation

Tags: bash, sed, directory, move, absolute-path

I'm trying to create a bash script based on a input file (list.txt). The input File contains a list of files with absolute path. The output should be a bash script (move.sh) which moves the files to another location, preserve the folder structure, but changing the target folder name slightly before.

the Input list.txt File example looks like this :

```
/In/Folder_1/SomeFoldername1/somefilename_x.mp3
/In/Folder_2/SomeFoldername2/somefilename_y.mp3
/In/Folder_3/SomeFoldername3/somefilename_z.mp3
```

The output file (move.sh) should looks like this after creation :

```
mv "/In/Folder_1/SomeFoldername1/somefilename_x.mp3"  /gain/Folder_1/
mv "/In/Folder_2/SomeFoldername2/somefilename_y.mp3"  /gain/Folder_2/
mv "/In/Folder_3/SomeFoldername3/somefilename_z.mp3"  /gain/Folder_3/
```

The folder structure should be preserved, more or less.

after executing the created bash script (move.sh), the result should looks like this :

```
/gain/Folder_1/somefilename_x.mp3
/gain/Folder_2/somefilename_y.mp3
/gain/Folder_3/somefilename_z.mp3
```

What I've done so far.

## 1. create a list of files with absolute path

```
find /In/ -iname "*.mp3" -type f > /home/maars/mp3/list.txt
```

## 2. create the move.sh script

```
cp -a /home/maars/mp3/list.txt /home/maars/mp3/move.sh 
# read the list and split the absolute path into fields
while IFS= read -r line;do
fields=($(printf "%s" "$line"|cut -d'/' --output-delimiter=' ' -f1-))
done < /home/maars/mp3/move.sh
# add the target path based on variables at the end of the line
sed -i -E "s|\.mp3|\.mp3"\"" /gain/"${fields[1]}"/|g" /home/maars/mp3/move.sh
sed -i "s|/In/|mv "\""/In/|g" /home/maars/mp3/move.sh
```

The script just use the value of `${fields[1]}`, which is Folder_1 and put this in all lines at the end. Instead of Folder_2 and Folder_3. 
The current result looks like

```
mv "/In/Folder_1/SomeFoldername1/somefilename_x.mp3"  /gain/Folder_1/
mv "/In/Folder_2/SomeFoldername2/somefilename_y.mp3"  /gain/Folder_1/
mv "/In/Folder_3/SomeFoldername3/somefilename_z.mp3"  /gain/Folder_1/
```

rsync is not an option since I need the full control of files to be moved.

What could I do better to solve this issue ?

**EDIT : @Socowi helped me a lot by pointing me in the right direction. After I did a deep dive into the World of Regex, I could solve my Issues. Thank you very much**

Comment: You wrote `done < /home/maars/mp3/move.sh`. Didn't you mean `done < /home/maars/mp3/list.txt`?

Comment: `done < /home/maars/mp3/move.sh` is just a copy of `done < /home/maars/mp3/list.txt`, as defined in line 1. I keep `done < /home/maars/mp3/list.txt` for other activities.

Comment: Ah, I see. Another question; do you want to move the mp3 files only or the complete directories? If you want to move only the mp3 files: Do the target directories already exist or should they be created?

Comment: only the mp3's. The target directories `/gain/Folder_x/` already exist.

Comment: But the directory `/gain/Folder_1/SomeFoldername1` does not exist. Ok.

Comment: In my script this folder currently  does not exist, that is correct. But not realy needed in my usecase. If it would be created it's okay - but not important.

Comment: Since you want to have `/gain/Folder_1/SomeFoldername1/somefilename_x.mp3` as the final result, you need to create `/gain/Folder_1/SomeFoldername1` first. `mv` cannot create directories.

Comment: this is clear. for clarification I adjusted the final view to:
`/gain/Folder_1/somefilename_x.mp3`
`/gain/Folder_2/somefilename_y.mp3`
`/gain/Folder_3//somefilename_z.mp3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The script just use the value of ${fields[1]}, which is Folder_1 and put this in all lines at the end. Instead of Folder_2 and Folder_3.

You iterate over all lines and update `fields` for every line. After you finished the loop, `fields` retains its value (from the last line). You would have to move the `sed` commands into your loop and make sure that only the current line is replaced by `sed`. However, there's a better way – see down below.

> What could I do better

There are a lot of things you could improve, for instance

- Creating the array `fields` with `mapfile -d/ fields` instead of `printf`+`cut`+`($())`. That way, you also wouldn't have problems with spaces in paths.
- Use `sed` only once instead of creating the array `fields` and using multiple `sed` commands. You can replace step 2 with this small script:

```
cp -a /home/maars/mp3/list.txt /home/maars/mp3/move.sh 
sed -i -E 's|^/[^/]*/([^/]*).*$|mv "&" "/gain/\1"|' /home/maars/mp3/move.sh
```

However, the best optimization would be to drop that three step approach and use only one script to find and move the files:

```
find /In/ -iname "*.mp3" -type f -exec rename -n 's|^/.*?/(.*?)/.*/(.*)$|/gain/$1/$2|' {} +
```

The `-n` option will print what will be renamed without actually renaming anything . Remove the `-n` when you are happy with the result. Here is the output:

```
rename(/In/Folder_1/SomeFoldername1/somefilename_x.mp3, /gain/Folder_1/somefilename_x.mp3)
rename(/In/Folder_2/SomeFoldername2/somefilename_y.mp3, /gain/Folder_2/somefilename_y.mp3)
rename(/In/Folder_3/SomeFoldername3/somefilename_z.mp3, /gain/Folder_3/somefilename_z.mp3)
```

Comment: I tried to apply `sed -iE 's|^/[^/]*/([^/]*).*$|mv "&" "/gain/\1"|' /home/maars/mp3/move.sh` but get an error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 40: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: @zumbi Seems like `sed` doesn't tolerate the shorthand form `-iE`. Try it with `-i -E` again. See edit.

Comment: It worked with `-i -E`
I need to play around with the `find /In/ -iname "*.mp3" -type f -exec rename -n 's|^/.*?/(.*?)/.*/(.*)$|/gain/$1/$2|' {} +` to understand it. because it does not give me any output yet.

Comment: Maybe you have a different `rename` than I had in mind. On Ubuntu `rename` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/file-rename`. The program is written by Larry Wall (see `man rename | grep -A1 AUTHOR`) and `rename --version` prints `/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20`. On other systems the very same command may have a different name, for instance `prename`. For more information see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/187122) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577767/6770384).

Comment: I needed to install the `rename` first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not builtin to bash, but the `mmv` command is nice for this kind of `mv` where you need to use wildcards in paths. Something like the following should work:

```
mmv "in/*/*/*" "#1/#3"
```

Note that this won't create the directories for you - but in your example above it looks like these already exist?