# Using Bash to Move Digits From Specific Location in Filename

Tags: regex, linux, bash, for-loop, filenames

I have file names in the following format:

```
images.jpeg-028
```

I would like to transform the file name of every file in a directory from the format above to the following format:

```
images-028.jpeg
```

All the numbers at the end of the filenames are three digits long.

Based on this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47587/renaming-multiple-files-by-adding-a-string-to-the-beginning) on another forum, I am thinking of something along the lines of:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i"\-(\d+) \-(\d+)"$i"; done
```

But am open to other Bash-based approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done countless file renaming tasks using `for` loops in `bash`, I now find the `rename` utility invaluable.

This should work for your case:

```
rename 's/\.jpeg-(\d+)/-$1.jpeg/g' images.jpeg-*
```

Note: I'm referring to the `File::Rename` module from `Perl`, *not* the `rename` utility that is included on many Linux distros in the `util-linux` package.

If you already have the version from `util-linux`, you may want to read this:

[Get the Perl rename utility instead of the built-in rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename).

If you're set on using a pure `bash` solution, or you just don't want the hassle of installing `rename`, this should work:

```
for i in images.jpeg-*; do
   mv "$i" "images-${i##*-}.jpeg"
done
```