# Linux: rename files containing ASCII-Code for capital letters

Tags: regex, linux, rename

I have a collection of files where the capital letters are replaced by their ASCII-code (example ;065 for A). How can I most effectively recursively rename them from the command line?

Since I don't want to make the mess worse, I unfortunately don't know how test any commands...

For me it would be no problem to modify the command for each letter.

Comment: Can you show a couple of sample "actual" full filenames that you have?

Comment: just create a simple bash script

Comment: An example for a filename would be
`171113_;077;066_;066rüssel_2018_;086ideotechniker.pdf` what would mean
`171113_MB_Brüssel_2018_Videotechniker.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

Many Linux distributions ship some variant or another of the [Perl rename script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename), sometimes as `prename`, sometimes as `rename`. Any variant will do, but not the Linux `rename` utility that isn't written in Perl (run it with no argument and see if the help text mentions perl anywhere). This script runs Perl code on file names, typically a regex replacement.

```
prename -n 's/;(03[2-9]|0[4-9][0-9]|1[01][0-9]|12[0-6])/chr($1)/eg' *
```

I made a regular expression that matches three-digit numbers that are the character code of a printable ASCII character. You may need to adjust it depending on exactly what can follow a semicolon. The `*` at the end says to rename all files in the current directory, it's just a normal shell wildcard. It's ok to include files that don't contain anything to rename: `prename` will just skip them.

The `-n` option says to show what would be done, but don't actually rename any file. Review the output. If you're happy with it, run the command again without `-n` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Thank you very much. This one works perfect. Does prename also have the possibility to recursively do this?

Comment: Not `prename` itself, but if your shell supports `**`, you can pass something like `**/*` to traverse subdirectories.